# Clear Laravel cache for a specific site / environment

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I'm using Laravel Forge and have a server with two sites/environments; production & staging.

As part of the deploy script for both of these I clear the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

However, the issue here is that this clears the cache completely; including the the production cache even if the deploy is only on staging.

Is there a way I can only clear a specific cache for the site the command it ran on?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Laravel Forge, why did you use a single command to clear the cache for staging and production? If you set it up correctly, it should have two different endpoints and two different commands

Comment: What you use for cache? One redis for stage and prod?

Comment: use putty the connect to your app